# How to add an extra Item in ComboBox using c#

Tags: c#, combobox

Currently i'm populating a combobox with items from a database.However, i want the first item of combobox to be "---Select---".I am using the following code.All the items from database are getting populated but not the item "---Select---". Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

```
private void popClass()
{
    cmbClass.Items.Clear();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cmbClass.Items.Add("---Select----");
    string sqlPS = @"SELECT * FROM tblclass_msb";
    try
    {
        using (FbConnection conPS = new FbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conPS.Open();
            using (FbCommand cmdPS = new FbCommand(sqlPS, conPS))
            {
                using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = cmdPS;
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    cmbClass.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    cmbClass.ValueMember = "c_id";
                    cmbClass.DisplayMember = "c_name";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("PC-->>" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

i have tried other solutions mentioned somewhere in the other threads but its not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add new row at zero position you an do it like this:

```
private void popClass()
{
    cmbClass.Items.Clear();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cmbClass.Items.Add("---Select----");
    string sqlPS = @"SELECT * FROM tblclass_msb";
    try
    {
        using (FbConnection conPS = new FbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conPS.Open();
            using (FbCommand cmdPS = new FbCommand(sqlPS, conPS))
            {
                using (FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = cmdPS;
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    DataRow dr=ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    dr["c_id"]=0;
                    dr["c_name"]="--Select--";
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt( dr,0);
                    cmbClass.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    cmbClass.ValueMember = "c_id";
                    cmbClass.DisplayMember = "c_name";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("PC-->>" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: use ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); instead

Comment: use ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt( dr,0);

Answer (score 0):

If you were connecting to SQL Server using SqlCommand, you could simply change the SQL statement to the following:

```
string sqlPS = @"select 0 as c_id, '--Select--' as c_name union SELECT c_id, c_name FROM tblclass_msb";
```

However, it looks like you're connecting to Firebird and I can't be sure if union is supported.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your query is not executing.It shows me error at "union"

Comment: Apologies, I can verify the solution works connecting to SQL Server, but it looks like you're using Firebird and I couldn't check if union is supported on that platform. At least you seem to have resolved the issue.